# How to migrate Community Builder Pages from Sandbox to Production?

Tags: community-builder

I am trying to migrate a community builder page from Sandbox to Production. First I exported the community builder page as solution.[image]

Then I added the Lightning Page to change set and deployed it on production, but I don't find an option set this page on Production.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically try 2 options:

1.Using changesets:

With Summer 2017 communities can be migrated using change sets (changeset object type is 'Network').

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets.htm?edition=&impact=

Option 2: check out the answer from mohith on the below stack link.

[Migration of Salesforce Communities configurations between environments](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/119939/migration-of-salesforce-communities-configurations-between-environments)

The pre-requisites for both move all lightning components,classes and other metadata to the target org before moving the communities.

Comment: Just add in the relevant text from the release note to make it clearer as the links do break at times.

Comment: I did not do that thinking it wont be ethical to copy mohith's answer to this post.

Comment: I was thinking of the release note not mohith's answer. sorry if that wasn't clear.